# Need help using StdDraw to draw a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array, stddraw

So I already have a method which reads a file which I have converted into a 2d array(therefore the dimensions of the array could be different each time depending on which file I use). Now I am trying to draw a rectangle using this and it wont work. My code is:

```
public static void drawBoard(String [][] board)  {

    for (int i = 0; (i < board.length); i++) { //line 88
        for (int j = 0; (j < board[0].length); j++) {
            int r = board.length;
            int c = board[0].length;
            double R = new Double(r);
            double C = new Double(c);

        StdDraw.setXscale(0,C);
        StdDraw.setYscale(0,R);
        StdDraw.setCanvasSize(500,500);
        StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.05);
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
        StdDraw.rectangle((C/2), (R/2), (C/2), (R/2));
        StdDraw.close();


    }
}
}
```

What can I do to fix this? How can I get it to draw a rectangle?
it says the error is in line 88 and that its a "java.lang.NullPointerException" error.

Answer (score 0):

`StdDraw.rectangle` expects input parameters of type `double`. You pass it input parameters of type `int`. This is ok but you might not want to do this. When calculating `C/2` and `R/2` you do [integer division](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Intro/expr-int-div.html) and thus you might accidentially round down. To fix this, you could initialize `C` and `R` as `double`.

Comment: I have changed it to a double (please see my edit) But I am stil getting the same issue...

Comment: Which is line 88?

Comment: you can do `double r = board.length;` and `double c = board.length[0];`

Comment: can you please share the stack trace?